# Truncating text after a specific number of lines in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, word-wrap

Is it possible to truncate a Label or a Text after a fixed number of lines in JavaFX? For the Web there is a CSS property called 'line-clamp'. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in JavaFX.

With a Label you can either choose to wrap the text or truncate it with ellipsis shown. With the Text object it is at least possible to specify the wrapping with.

**Not wrapped and not truncated:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eir mod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
```

**Wrapped and not truncated:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliquyam
```

**Not wrapped and truncated:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, ...
```

**Wrapped and truncated after 2 lines (desired behavior):**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore ...
```

Comment: no, that's not supported by core fx - 3rd party extensions might (maybe controlsfx, didn't check, though)

Comment: @kleopatra That's what I thought. ControlsFX doesn't have anything like this in their library.

Comment: Maybe [RichTextFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX)? Not sure if it supports that though.

Comment: @James_D Doesn't seem like that.

Comment: I'm not sure a third-party library could implement what you want, at least not without hacking into the internals of JavaFX. I find JavaFX hides a lot of useful information about text and fonts in private code. And that's assuming that private API could do what you want in the first place.

Comment: @Slaw - that's so true.. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've came up with fairly basic solution (that can be further improved).

```
public class MultiLineLabel extends VBox {

    private final String text;
    private final List<Label> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public MultiLineLabel(String text, int maxNumberOfLines) {

        if (maxNumberOfLines < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        this.text = text;

        // Create num. of lines labels
        for (int i=0; i<maxNumberOfLines; i++) {
            final Label label = new Label();
            lines.add(label);
            label.setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.CLIP);
        }

        getChildren().addAll(lines);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();

        String remainingText =  this.text;

        for (Iterator<Label> iterator = lines.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            final Label currentLine = iterator.next();

            // If this is the last line, just set the text and finish
            if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
                currentLine.setText(remainingText);
                currentLine.setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.ELLIPSIS);
                break;
            } else {
                final String textThatFitsInThisLine = Utils.computeClippedText(currentLine.getFont(), remainingText, this.getWidth(), OverrunStyle.CLIP, null);
                currentLine.setText(textThatFitsInThisLine);
                remainingText = remainingText.substring(textThatFitsInThisLine.length());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

... that can then be used like:

```
public class MultiLineLabelSSCCE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final MultiLineLabel multiLineLabel =
                  new MultiLineLabel("This is some interesting text. The question is whether it's truncated properly. Let's see.", 3);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(multiLineLabel));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Demo (of the above solution):

[image]

I hope this suffices for what you need it for.

**Side note:**

This solutions is based on `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.Utils` which is considered an implementation detail and is not part of JavaFx API. To run the code using this solution you might need to add:
`--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin=org.example`
to your *run configuration* (VM options)

Comment: A little tweak: call `super.layoutChildren()` at the end of the method to avoid the flickering of the ellipsis. But anyway it's a working solution. Thank you.